# Laravel Route List Fatal Throwable Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I can list all my route in console, but when I add this on my route.php, I've got fatal error

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as'=>'admin.'], function () {
        Route::get('/',         ['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'AdminController@dashboard']);
        Route::resource('questions','QuestionController');
    });
```

[image]

and this is on my Middleware/IsAdmin.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('home');
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
Even I only got this, it still error.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'is_admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as'=>'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/',         ['as'=>'dashboard', 'uses'=>'AdminController@dashboard']);
});
```

**Update 3 - AdminController**

```
...
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    private $page_name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        //when I comment this below, it works.
        $this->page_name = ucfirst(substr(\Request::route()->getName(), strpos(\Request::route()->getName(), "/") + 1)); 
    }
...
```

[image]

Comment: search in your application for `getName()` and share that code ? I think it is in `is_admin` middleware

Comment: updated my code @C2486

Comment: can you remove this `'middleware' => 'is_admin'` from route and check `route:list` works for you or not ?

Comment: problem may be in `auth()->user()->isAdmin()`

Comment: I removed the `'middleware' => 'is_admin'` and it still not works

Comment: remove dot (`.`) from here `'as'=>'admin.'`

Comment: also tried  `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: do either of these 2 controllers have custom constructors?

Comment: yeah there is I updated my code

Comment: Could you run `php artisan route:list -v` to see the details error please?

Comment: updated my post with error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you have:

```
$this->page_name = ucfirst(substr(\Request::route()->getName(), strpos(\Request::route()->getName(), "/") + 1));
```

in controller constructor (you already noticed).

When you are using console, you don't have any route so it won't work.

If you really need this line you can wrap this with additional condition:

```
if (!app()->runningInConsole())
{
    $this->page_name = ucfirst(substr(\Request::route()->getName(), strpos(\Request::route()->getName(), "/") + 1));
}
```

but you can also extract this line into separate method and use it in other methods when needed.